# .net Forming Generic type from the arbitrary xml

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, nservicebus

I need to convert the XML which comes as a message from a different system into the Type which i am looking. For example if i have a Generic interface like

```
 IMessageHandler<CustomerCreated>
```

Then when the XML comes with i should be able to Find the type and create a Genric type. So that i can use the Dependency injection to call the appropriate class which would have implemented the method.
I have Seen this kind of Code in NServiceBus so i am the tag as well

Comment: Can you post a sample of the XML data?

Comment: not able to stackoverflow markup. any idea

Comment: Add four spaces in front of every line to make it into a code-block. Cheap way would be to paste it as is, and hope someone else re-formats it for you.